# Loading new commit to GitHub replacing the old, bad, one

Tags: git, github

Sorry, I'm a Git nube, but I managed to create
a "good" master on my local machine, and now I'd like
to replace an existing master on my GitHub account.

Years ago I set up a GitHub account, and somehow got a commit to it,
but the data was bad and not what I wanted.

Now I finally have a good commit I have ready and want to
send up to it.

I would really like to keep the GitHub account name but
completely remove any commit that was there.  I think GitHub
was saying something about changing the account name or something.

This was my first attempt:

```
c:\Dev>git remote add XYZ https://github.com/[]/[].git

c:\Dev>git push XYZ master
Username for ...
Password for ...
To https://github.com/[]/[].git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[]/[].git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I saw a post about trying to "fix" it by using these commands:
(This might have just messed it up more, I don't know)

```
c:\Dev>git push XYZ master
Username for ...
Password for ...
To https://github.com/[]/[].git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[]/[].git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

c:\Dev>git fetch XYZ master
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 6.83 KiB | 55.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/[]/[]
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
* [new branch]      master     -> XYZ/master

c:\Dev>git merge XYZ master
merge: XYZ - not something we can merge
```

Then I tried again..

```
c:\Dev>git push XYZ master
Username for ...
Password for ...
To https://github.com/[]/[].git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[]/[].git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm completely confused, and don't want to mess up my local master
by accident, so what do I need to do to get my local master
uploaded into my GitHub account?

I have a GitHub Desktop app, but that confuses me also
especially about the two different, old and new, masters I have on there.

And I sure don't want to "merge" the two, as I'd really like to just totally
get rid of anything from the original commit to GitHub.

It's very possible that the original local master was from
a different directory, with different source.

I saw something about that "force" wasn't that great to use,
and I'd like to not use that if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You should include a branch diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Your remote master branch contains work that is not included in your local master branch.

This is why the remote master branch is rejecting your changes as you would overwrote them with your new local master's changes (this is usually not wanted behavior as you could lose code written by one of your fellow developers).

You can specify to overwrite your remote master with your local by specifying the --force flag:

```
git push XYZ master --force
```

Warning: Keep in mind that this overwrites what is stored in your remote GitHub repo and it is lost if you do not have another copy.

Reference:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!!

I tried it and got this back
so I'm guessing it worked:

```
c:\Dev\>git push XYZ master --force
Username for ...
Password for ...
Enumerating objects: 69, done.
Counting objects: 100% (69/69), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 434.79 KiB | 7.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 69 (delta 36), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (36/36), done.
To https://github.com/[]/[].git
+ ec4c115...8e2805a master -> master (forced update)
```